# assert that only single child is passed in `this.props.children`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way, using `React.PropTypes` to demand that only a single child is passed in `this.props.children` ?

What I currently have in my code in cases where a single child has to be provided is to declare that children are mandatory in `propTypes`:

```
propTypes {
    ...
    children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired
}
```

… and then assert that the correct number is passed in the `render` method, e.g. by using:

```
const singleChild = this.props.children;
```

… which is guaranteed to bark if more than one children are passed.

I am wondering:

1. if there is a better, perhaps more idiomatic way?
2. if there is further any way to demand that the passed children be of some specific element types (though I guess that sort of defeats the purpose of `this.props.children` which is to allow passing of more or less arbitrary elements).

Comment: The documentation seems to be mentioning the same as what you did https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#requiring-single-children. You could also write a custom validator as described in the documentation but it might me more verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [PropTypes documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#requiring-single-child), `PropTypes.element.isRequired` is the idiomatic way of specifying that a component has only a single child.

```js
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
};
```

Another option is to use [React.Children.only()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenonly) which will return the child React element if there is only one, otherwise an error.  This is handy if you need guarantees about the number of children at runtime, which propTypes isn't meant for.

In regards to the second part of your question (enforcing the child has a specific element type), [Airbnb's custom PropType validators](https://github.com/airbnb/prop-types) includes a `componentWithName`.  Its usage is as follows:

> componentWithName: restrict the prop to only allow a component with a certain name/displayName. Accepts a string, or a regular expression. Also accepts an options object with an optional stripHOCs array of string HOC names to strip off before validating; an HOC name must not contain parentheses and must be in camelCase.

```
foo: componentWithName('Component')
foo: componentWithName('Component', { stripHOCs: ['withDirection', 'withStyles'] })
```